# How to overlay or add image on video in iOS obj c

Tags: ios, xcode

Im confused ,to add a image on the video .is any other know ,how to add it on video .please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure it's clear what you want to accomplish or what you've tried. Do you want to overlay an `UIImageView` on a `MPMoviePlayer`? Or something else? Some examples of your code would help too.

Comment: Yes, UIImageView on a MPMoviePlayer